# How to set format in Excel while writing Pandas dataframe using xlswriter

Tags: excel, pandas

How to set font size and font type for entire excel workbook while writing Pandas dataframe to excel using xlswriter.

I tried,

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_file, engine = 'xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, 'Test', index = False, startrow = 0)#, float_format ="%.2g")
workbook = writer.book
format = workbook.add_format()
format.set_font_size(8)
format.set_font_name('Times New Roman')
writer.save()
```

But font size and type is not set? I am not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer, we need to apply the format using,

```py
worksheet = writer.sheets['Test']    
for i in range(1000):
    worksheet.set_row(i, cell_format=format)
```